# How does VLC Media player implement HTTP Streaming?

Tags: c#, java, http, streaming

How does VLC Media player implement HTTP Streaming?

I am aware that, VLC Media player can be used as a streaming server and also a streaming client.

My requirement is to stream(over HTTP) a proprietary protocol data from the server to clients and I am not comfortable with C/C++ code. I am comfortable with C# and Java. Can somebody point me to example implementations of HTTP Streaming in either C# or Java?

Comment: Do you just want to stream data? Or video?

Comment: It is just data, which needs to reach the clients in realtime or with very low latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Streaming" in this context simply means sending a large binary HTTP response to a request. You can get a reference to the output stream in Java by calling **HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream**. You can then send whatever data you like through the stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can review [the VLC source](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java Media Framework ([link](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/)) provides video streaming. You can implement not only a client but also the server using this API.

If I remember correctly the SDK includes some examples that might help.

Answer (score 0):

what about CLI (command line interface)?

```
vlc --repeat /path_to/1.avi --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8000}'
```